# Java FX How to properly add a few imageviews and then change position of this imageviews by the mouse

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, imageview

I'm new into JavaFX and object programming so I need some help. Let's assume that I have FXML files called FXML1 and FXML2 and two Controllers for each one of them called FXML1_Controller and FXML2_Controller. In the FXML1 I have a few Combobox with Integer values and one Button. I would like to add by this Button some Imageview's to FXML2, e.g. if Combobox1 value is 2 so I want to have added two ImageView1 in FXML2 view, if Combobox2 value is 1 I would like to have added one ImageView2 to FXML2 view, etc. Then I would like to have opportunity to change position (X,Y co-ordinates) of this ImageView's by Drag-and-Drop of mouse and be able to set this X and Y to variables, because I must export them to .xml file.

I stuck when I wanted to move ImageView. I added ImageViews to FXML2 by Button from FXML1. It works, I can see them in FXML2, but I don't know how to refer to them now. I know that my thinking and code could be wrong, but I'm pasting it.

I created a new group for ImageViews, I looped creating ImageViews by loop 'for' and added them to group. Next I used FXMLLoader to load FXML2.fxml and I added children to anchorpane of FXML2. All this fragments of code are in Button's MouseEvent in FXML1.

```
//Creating group

Group ImageView1_group = new Group();

//Loop

 for (int i=0; i<ImageView1_amount;i++){

        ImageView ImageView1 = new ImageView("ImageView1.svg");
        ImageView1.setId("ImageView1_"+i);
        ImageView1.setY(MainPaneHeight/2);
        ImageView1.setX(MainPaneWidth/2);
        ImageView1_group.getChildren().add(ImageView1);
    }

//
FXMLLoader Loader = new FXMLLoader();

Loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML2"));
        try {
            anchorpane.getChildren().clear();
            Pane newLoadedPane = Loader.load();
            anchorpane.getChildren().addAll(ImageView1_group);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I added a picture that shows what I would like to get. All added elements must be able to be moved with the mouse. Thank you for any advice.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sou5v.png

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: thanks, that wasn't my real code, it was an example with which I wanted to show my problem and it was written in a careless way.

Comment: better not be careless in your question if you want careful answers :)